# Cypress conditional statement for a disabled button element

Tags: cypress

Trying to click a button based on another element with enabled/disabled status. For some reason, my disabled check code is not working and it always ends in another statement ('No existing routes found') even though the UI has a select button enabled.

```js
cy.get('voyage-suggested-routes')
  .find('button.selectButton')
  .then(($routes) => {
    if ($routes.is(":disabled")) {
      cy.log("No existing routes found...")
    } else {
      cy.log("Deleting......")
      cy.get('.delete-button').click({ force: true, multiple: true })
    }
  });
```

This is the DOM: (There are 3 elements by default and a delete option will be there for each Select button if it is not disabled.)

```html
<button class="selectButton" disabled route="1">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="..."></path></svg>
        SELECT
</button>
```

Tried the jquery method as well but the same result.

```js
var btnStatus = Cypress.$('.selectButton')
  .is(":disabled");

if (btnStatus == true) {
  cy.log("Deleting......")
  cy.get('.delete-button').click({ force: true, multiple: true })
} else {
  cy.log("No existing routes found...")
}
```

What am I missing?

**Update 1:**
After Electron's input, my new code is:

```
 cy.get('voyage-suggested-routes')
     .find('button.selectButton')
     .then(($routes) => {
         if ($routes.is(":disabled").length === 0) {
            cy.log("No existing routes found...")
         } else {
            cy.log("Deleting......")
            cy.get('.delete-button').click({ force: true, multiple: true })
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs [jQuery .is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

> **Description:** Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true ***if at least one*** of these elements matches the given arguments.

So if only one route is disabled, the delete will not go ahead.

Try using a filter to see if any are disabled.

```js
cy.get('voyage-suggested-routes')
  .find('button.selectButton')
  .then(($routes) => {
    const disabled = $routes.filter(":disabled")
    if ($routes.length === disabled.length) {
      cy.log("No existing routes found...")
    } else {
      cy.log("Deleting......")
      cy.get('.delete-button').click({ force: true, multiple: true })
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you need `each` instead of `then`, like this:

```
.each(($routes) => {
```

in order to perform as many actions as there are button elements.

**Edit:** *as Electron stated in the comments, the suggestion below will fail a test if all buttons are disabled, so take care if you use it.*

And to better optimize your code, your can set the selector as `.find('button.selectButton:not(:disabled)')` then you don't need `if` block at all, just the delete statement.

Comment: I wondered about that too, but `.find('button.selectButton:not(:disabled)')` will fail the test if there are none (ref "conditional" in the question)

Comment: You're completely right, just tested it, it will fail a test. Hmm, I'll edit the answer...

Comment: One of the quirks of Cypress - commands always fail. I'm looking forward to seeing a `{ maybe: true }` option to allow soft testing.

Comment: Thank you Zaista. Well, the reason I put `.then` instead of `.each` is, as soon as it identifies one enabled select element, it will click on delete buttons as I am passing `multiple: true`. Though it's not a suggested approach, how can I possibly take care of the scenario when all 3 are disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a custom command which conditionally runs a callback, depending on the result of filtering by given selector.

Not a lot of difference to `.then(($routes) => { const disabled = $routes.filter(":disabled")` pattern. Unfortunately ending part of a chain is quite difficult, as the whole test is considered one chain.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('maybe', {prevSubject:true}, (subject, selector, callback) => {
  const result = subject.filter(selector)
  if (result.length > 0) {
    cy.log(`Maybe: Found ${result.length} "${selector}"`)      
    cy.wrap(result).then(callback)
    return
  }
  cy.log(`Maybe: Not found: "${selector}"`)
})


cy.get('button.selectButton')
  .maybe(':not(:disabled)', ($result) => {

    // can use result of filter here
    console.log('result is', $result))  

    // or conditionally run some other commands
    cy.log(`Deleting...`)
    cy.get('.delete-button').click({ force: true, multiple: true })
  })

// runs either way
cy.wrap('something')
  .then(x => console.log('next', x))
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the best approach, but unfortunately, it ends the whole test and not just the action chain @Electron.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have much time on it. Here's a revision, but it's not a lot different from @Paolo's answer.